# For FIFA World Cup Russia 2018, do I still need 6 months on my passport if I'm using Fan ID?

Tags: passports, russia, sports-events, world-cup

The passport validity in Russia must  be at least 6 months after the expiry date of the visa. Is that applicable on world cup free visa or Fan ID?

Comment: My fleight is after 7 days

Comment: Yes is it possible to enter Russia with a passport valid only 5 months?

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to enter with less than 6 months before expiry date according to [Russian consulate in Portugal](http://www.consul.embrussia.ru/node/120):

> Для въезда в Российскую Федерацию минимальный срок окончания действия паспорта иностранного гражданина: 28.07.2018

*For entering Russia, earliest [accepted] passport expiry date is 28.07.2018*

This makes sense, since you have to leave Russia before 25.07.2018 anyway if travelling on Fan ID. However, the rest of 'nets are utterly silent on the issue so maybe they thought this one up.

If we look up [the actual law](http://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_147218/b8158b9d1804f736feb8b2fddd37c6249c2e2c27/), there's nothing concrete there.

> В течение периода, начинающегося за десять дней до даты проведения
>   первого матча чемпионата мира по футболу FIFA 2018 года или Кубка
>   конфедераций FIFA 2017 года и заканчивающегося в день проведения
>   последнего матча чемпионата мира по футболу FIFA 2018 года или Кубка
>   конфедераций FIFA 2017 года, въезд в Российскую Федерацию иностранных
>   граждан и лиц без гражданства, прибывающих в Российскую Федерацию в
>   качестве зрителей спортивных соревнований, осуществляется без
>   оформления виз **по действительным документам, удостоверяющим личность и
>   признаваемым Российской Федерацией в этом качестве**,
>   персонифицированной карте зрителя, получаемой такими гражданами и
>   лицами без гражданства при наличии входного билета на матч или
>   документа, дающего право на получение входного билета на матч.

They just state that your passport has to be valid and accepted by Russia, but nothing about expiry date in the future. I would call your local Russian embassy if I were you.